# In Visual Studio, how do you print the list of breakpoints to a file?

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to print a list of my breakpoints to a file, but I don't see a way to do it other than taking a screenshot of the Breakpoints window and printing that. Searching the Internet for "print breakpoints Visual Studio" brings up a lot of information about getting breakpoints to print information, but not about how to print out the breakpoints themselves.

As a bonus, I'd like to display more information within the Breakpoints window as well as in the file that I can (ideally) print out to. In particular, I'd like to be able to add a column to display the full filepath for the breakpoint. I would expect to see such an option under Tools/Settings, but I don't.

Comment: **If** this is possible it would require an add-on.  If you cannot find an add-on it likely does not exist.

Comment: @Alan, I would recommend adding your solution as an answer instead of an update to your question.

Comment: @heavyd, I followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions of Visual Studio that include the Nuget Package Manager (VS 2012+ or VS 2010 with the Nuget plugin) you can use the Package Manager Console (View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console).  The console is a Powershell console and has been injected with a variable `$dte` which represents the [Visual Studio automation interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx).

You can get to the breakpoints using the `$dte.Debugger.Breakpoints` property, which you can then output to a file using the following command:

```
$dte.Debugger.Breakpoints | select Name  | Out-File breakpoints.txt
```

This will output the Filename, line number and character of each breakpoint to the file `breakpoints.txt`.

You can select any of the properties of the [Breakpoint Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.breakpoint.aspx) and do any other formatting using Powershell prior to sending the output to the file.

Comment: This is nice. It's worth the two minutes or so to download and install the (free) Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: [Version for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca)

Answer (score 1):

I now see that it's possible to export breakpoints to an XML file (by clicking the first curved arrow near the top of the Breakpoints window). The XML contains, among other information, the full path to each file, which is more than the GUI displays. Of course, the XML file contains a lot more information than I would want to print, but I could process it, manually or automatically, to make it more manageable.